# How can one set full justification within left-justified (\raggedright) text?

Tags: horizontal-alignment

How can one set full justification within left-justified (`{\raggedright [...]}`) text?

An example of where I need full justification is here:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\begin{document}

Document body.

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
  \SingleSpacing
\bibitem{ABC}
  {\raggedright \hyphenpenalty=10000 \exhyphenpenalty=10000
  Plenty of left-aligned text. Plenty of left-aligned text. Plenty of left-aligned text. Plenty of left-aligned text. Plenty of left-aligned text. Plenty of left-aligned text. Plenty of left-aligned text. Plenty of left-aligned text. Plenty of left-aligned text. Plenty of left-aligned text. Plenty of left-aligned text. Plenty of left-aligned text. Plenty of left-aligned text. Plenty of left-aligned text. Plenty of left-aligned text.
  \begin{list}{\(\bullet\)}
  \item Plenty of left-aligned text. Plenty of left-aligned text. Plenty of left-aligned text. Plenty of left-aligned text. Plenty of left-aligned text. Plenty of left-aligned text. Plenty of left-aligned text. \par
      \emph{Text I would like to be justified. Text I would like to be justified. Text I would like to be justified. Text I would like to be justified. Text I would like to be justified. Text I would like to be justified. Text I would like to be justified. Text I would like to be justified. Text I would like to be justified. Text I would like to be justified. Text I would like to be justified.}
  \end{list}
  }
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

It is self-explanatory.

*Note: There are probably more minimal examples, but (aside from me needing full justification in this particular context) this one will do for a context where something obvious such as "set a smaller scope for `\raggedright` doesn't work.*

Answer (score 25, accepted):

use package `ragged2e` then you have a macro which allows to justify the text:

```
\usepackage{ragged2e}
....
  {\justifying\emph{Text I would....}\par}
```

`\par` is needed to activate the setting

Comment: In my case I also need `\noindent` after `\justifying`, but I understand this is a stylistic matter where people have different tastes.

Comment: In my case, it works with  {\justifying Text  \par} only.

Answer (score 12):

By restoring the meaning of `\rightskip` and `\leftskip`, a justified paragraph is also obtained. Wrapping this in a macro called `\justified` works similar to `\raggedleft` and `\raggedright`:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\justified}{%
  \rightskip\z@skip%
  \leftskip\z@skip}
\makeatother
```

If you wish to restore a paragraph indent, you can also place it inside the `\justified` definition. Default would be `20pt`.

Comment: I am sorry, but how can I fully justify (left and right) my whole document?

Comment: @DiaaAbidou: Issue `\justifying` (from [`ragged2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ragged2e)) at the start of your document. What `\documentclass` (or setup) do you have that doesn't show this naturally?

Comment: I am sorry it was my bad, I found it naturally fully justified, but your input was informative to me. Many thanks for your consideration.

Answer (score 11):

You could just wrap the text in a `\parbox` set to the `\linewidth`. (I've used the `kantlipsum` package to show some more realistic text.)  One drawback of this solution as noted in the comments is that the resulting `\parbox` will not break across pages.  For some purposes this might be acceptable, but for most applications, Herbert's solution using the `ragged2e` package is to be preferred.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}

Document body.

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
  \SingleSpacing
\bibitem{ABC}
  {\raggedright \hyphenpenalty=10000 \exhyphenpenalty=10000
  \kant[1]
  \begin{list}{\(\bullet\)}
  \item \kant[1]
      \parbox{\linewidth}{\emph{Text I would like to be justified. Text I would like to be justified. Text I would like to be justified. Text I would like to be justified. Text I would like to be justified. Text I would like to be justified. Text I would like to be justified. Text I would like to be justified. Text I would like to be justified. Text I would like to be justified. Text I would like to be justified.}}
  \end{list}
  }
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: This has a big limitation/feature: the justified block won't be broken across pages.