# Is there a way to justify ALL LINES of a given paragraph?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, multicol

I would like to set the paragraph alignment to "all lines", like in Adobe InDesign, see screenshot below:

[image]

Is there a way to do it with LaTeX?

And if yes, will it work with the [multicol](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/multicol) package ?

Thanks in advance.

**Regarding the duplicate question:** sorry, but I thought in tems of text justification ("alignment"), not overall shape ("rectangles").

Comment: for a single paragraph, you will need to isolate that paragraph in a group, then apply `\noindent` at the beginning, and `\parindent=0pt \par` at the end. if applying it to all paragraphs, you should add space between paragraphs so that a reader can tell where each one begins and ends.  writing for this style is nontrivial, if you want the result to look good.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? [Is there a tool that makes paragraphs into rectangles?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/116573) (Edit: note the end of egreg's answer.)

Comment: The `{\parfillskip=0pt \emergencystretch=.5\textwidth \par}` trick is what I was looking for. Thanks Torbjørn T.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How can one set full justification within left-justified (`\raggedright`) text?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/89680/5764) The solution approach uses `\justifying` from [`ragged2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ragged2e).

Comment: Werner, what I want is justification of the very last line of the paragraph, too. The solution in the post linked by Torbjørn T. does exactly that.